# How to identify unsynced entities? Is the client the one who generates the Ids?

Tags: java, database, synchronization, primary-key, data-synchronization

Let's say I want to synchronize (using HTTP protocol) an entity called `Person`. So, the persons in client (mobile/desktop/whatever) is a mirror-replicate of persons exist in server's database. Obviously, server owns all persons and client owns only the specific user's persons.

Consider the following case.

Client is offline. While he is offline, he creates a `Person` and because he can't connect to the  server, he keeps this person to a local storage. Let's say a local database (SQLite or whatever). **The moment this happens, how is/should this person identified?**

Before I started implementing the whole thing, I thought the server should be the one that generates the IDs of persons coming to him. However, when I started implementing, I start facing this problem.

In case the server generates the IDs, since the person is never seen by the server, client must give it an ID in order to be able to find the person and obviously use this ID to store the person into his local storage. Now, when client comes online, he will send the person to server. Server, gives it an ID and stores it in his own database. After that, client will request for any kind of person changes that happened after his last time of synced and server will return this specific person.

Lets make an example. Client is offline, creates 100 Persons and stores them to his local storage. Person 1, Person 2, Person 3, etc... Now, he gets connected to the server and he sends all 100 persons. Since the connection happens over HTTP, client makes a post request to `post-persons` endpoint. Then, server generates IDs (either incremental or UUIDs) and probably change some other properties as well. Now, client access `get-persons` endpoint and he sees 100 updated persons, each one of them having a new ID that he could not know about. **How does the client know which of these persons correspond to persons that client already has?** Removing the old client's 100 persons, and inserting 100 new with server ID seems unorthodox. With other words, Person 1 known by the client, is stored as Person [uuid] in server, and server returns it as Person [uuid]. How client knows that his Person 1 corresponds to Person [uuid]? A solution might be, to send client's IDs to server, and server will respond like Person [uuid] 1. Now client knows, his 1 is this one. And to me, this seems even more unorthodox.

Second option is to have the clients generate UUIDs either they are offline, either online. This solution seems the "simplest" approach when it comes to implementation by my side. Client creates Person [uuid]. When he comes online, he sends it to server. After that client accesses `get-persons` and he gets as respond an update Person [uuid]. He easily identifies & stores it in his local storage. The server does not generate any kind of ID for persons.

Is there anything I am missing? Till now, I thought servers are the ones that generate the IDs of syncable entities, but I think the second approach is easier to implement and more comprehensive. But does it introduce any kind of "danger" for later?

There are no explicit requirements when it comes to what kind of ID I will use to client, or the server. However, I am aware of the trade-offs using UUIDs over simple increment numbers.

The stack (even though I consider it irrelevant):

- Spring boot as server among Hibernate and MySQL
- Client with Hibernate and H2 standalone as local storage
- Everything Java 8

Answer (score 0):

There are other possible solutions, and the best one depends on your particular situation - whether you need to maintain local relations, etc.

---

**The first solution keeps using IDs with no logic around it on the server.**

Don't generate ID at all and store persons without it (if possible), and when synced, the server returns IDs, and you change them locally.

Thus, it's simple to know which persons are already in sync with the server (those with ID) and which are not yet known to the server.

It's also simple to implement INSERT/UPDATE logic.

However, this solution may be a problem if you need to maintain local relations.

When you need local relations, you can generate temporary IDs. Let's say that you want a numeric ID, and so all positive IDs are those that are already synced, and negative IDs are those that are temporary.

When synced with the server, you obtain new IDs from the server (positive ones), and you simply rewrite all IDs in your local database. That's, however, a bit error-prone as you have to be sure to update all relations.

You can also have localId and serverId. Technically, you only need serverId to be globally unique to store persons on your server. You keep serverId empty and fill it once the entity is synchronized with the server (the server returns it). And you can generate localId as you want and use it for local relations. However, this can be a problematic approach if you need to have several clients in sync, and each of them would like to generate its own local IDs.

---

**The second approach is to use ID pools. It needs a bit of work on the server and storing assigned pools.**

You can allocate a pool of IDs for the given client. The client must be online at least once, and the server sends its unique offset.

Depending on your needs, you can have, for example, an 8-byte identifier (64 bits). The first 36 bits can be used for the offset, so your server can manage 2^36 clients. And the last 28 bits are free to use by the client.

So the client just increments the internal counter whenever it needs a new ID and adds the unique offset => gets a globally unique identifier.

Comment: I have think most of what you said already. I really do not want to introduce the change of IDs. Person might have child entities. Changing the ID of a person means I have to change the foreign key of the children too. This goes more complex. (I think hibernate won't even let me). However, I want to ask. Why you did not mention anything about creating the ID (one and final) in the client? I have the doubts for it as well. I am not sure why, but the way I see it, it is the most "understandable" & "easy to implement" solution.

Comment: Sure, changing IDs is probably not a good approach when you need to maintain relations. It's good for simple entity synchronization. I actually mentioned locally generated IDs with the ID pool approach. That's basically creating IDs locally but with centrally maintained strategy. I'm not a fan of completely random IDs. It's unpredictable.